# Set events in fullcalendar from array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, fullcalendar, dom-events

I'm using fullcalendar, but I want to set events from array, for example:

```
var countries = new Array();
countries[0] = {'title':'España', 'start':new Date(y, m, d+4, 19, 0), url:'http://google.com/'};
countries[1] = {'title':'Portugal', 'start':new Date(y, m, 22, 22, 0)};
```

This is a static example, I'll get this array and in each case I'd have 3 or 9 or ... differents events.

But example is:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    events: [ 
        {
            title: 'example',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
            allDay: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            start: new Date(y, m, 28),
            end: new Date(y, m, 29),
            url: 'http://google.com/'
        },         
    ]
});
```

How can I remove this two example events and set only my array "countries"?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removes events from the calendar.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' [, idOrFilter ] )
```

Dynamically adds an event source.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source )
```

From here:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/addEventSource

Comment: Hello kahosk , i am already using the addEventSource but it is not adding to my calendar can you please help me with some example you implemented i have a javascript object {id: '1',  resourceId: '234001', start:'2017-05-07T02:00:00',  end: '2017-05-07T07:00:00',  title: 'event 1' 
      }

Comment: Can you expand this to give example of what would be in the "source" variable?

Comment: @jroyce As per the documentation on the page linked to by @Kahosk, "Source may be an Array/URL/Function just as in the events option". So, for example, if the Events in your Event Source were stored in an array the value of your `source` parameter would be the array, as described for Events here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-array

Answer (score 6):

If you are using fullcalendar v4 there are a bunch of API changes mentioned in a Github [issue](https://github.com/StickNitro/ngx-fullcalendar/issues/10).

You would need to use the new API to get all of the event objects from the calendar and call the remove method on all of them.

After removing you need to use `calendar.addEvent(event)` to add all of your events.

We don't want to re-render the full calendar after adding each event so we wrap this into a batch rendering which only causes one re-rendering.

`newEvents` is the array of the events you want to add.

```
// batch every modification into one re-render
calendar.batchRendering(() => {
    // remove all events
    calendar.getEvents().forEach(event => event.remove());

    // add your new events
    newEvents.forEach(event => calendar.addEvent(event));
});
```

Hope this helped someone :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  calendar.batchRendering(() => {
    // remove all events
    calendar.getEvents().forEach(event => event.remove());
    // add your new events source
    calendar.addEventSource(events);
  });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.